# propertyChangeListeners chain reacting, causing overflow

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, propertychangelistener

Just a snippet of code.  Doing a project for class where I have to convert Celsius, Fahrenheit and Kelvin based on a change to their respective `JFormattedTextFields`.  The problem is that when the `listener` reacts to the change in Celsius, my program changes Fahrenheit, which then reacts to my Fahrenheit listener, which reacts my Celsius listener again, and so on.  I haven't worked in my Kelvin stuff yet due to this problem.  I doubt my code is needed, since this is more of a conceptual problem, but here it is anyway:

```
private class ValueChangeHandler implements PropertyChangeListener
{
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) 
    {

        Object celsiusChange = event.getSource();
        Object fahrenheitChange = event.getSource();
        Object kelvinChange = event.getSource();
        if(celsiusChange == celsiusField)
        {

            tempCelsius = (Double)celsiusField.getValue();
            tempFahrenheit = celToFah(tempCelsius);
            tempKelvin = celToKel(tempCelsius);
            fahrenheitField.setValue(tempFahrenheit);
            kelvinField.setValue(tempKelvin);

        }

        else if(fahrenheitChange == fahrenheitField)
        {

            tempFahrenheit = (Double)fahrenheitField.getValue();
            tempCelsius = fahToCel(tempFahrenheit);
            tempKelvin = fahToKel(tempFahrenheit);
            celsiusField.setValue(tempCelsius);
            kelvinField.setValue(tempKelvin);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe. Here's a working [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513) from which to start.

Comment: See also this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/index.html), which uses `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 1):

A `PropertyChangeEvent` is fired only if the new value is `not equals` to the previous one. So i suppose there is a problem with your `celToKel` and `fahToKel`.

For example, converting a celsius tempature C1 in Fahrenheit and again in Celius results in a C2 which is not equals to C1.

Another solution could be to remove the listener before setting the value and to add it again after.

```
public class ValueChangeHandler implements PropertyChangeListener
{
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent event)
    {
        ...
        fahrenheitField.removePropertyChangeListener("value", this);
        fahrenheitField.setValue(tempFahrenheit);
        fahrenheitField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);
        ...
    }
}
```

Checks also that your listener is bound only to the value property

```
fahrenheitField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);
```

and not to all the properties

```
fahrenheitField.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
```