# Update child (panel) of CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

My main `JFrame` content panel which is card layout and I have added many (say `panel1`, `panel2`) panel as card. I would like to update UI `panel1` when something changes in `panel2`.

How to update child (panel) of `CardLayout` in Swing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), is the key to this. In particular, both panels could listen to a common model, which would fire events to update each listening panel. Examples using `PropertyChangeListener` may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a reference to the target of what you want to change, and use some kind of callback function to detect the changes. Use the stored reference in the callback function. How you specifically implement this should be whatever makes most sense for your code... but what you are trying to do is a simple task.