# Java Swing and the Observer Pattern

Tags: java, swing, oop, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I'm looking for a way to cleanly organize my UI code in Swing.

Let's say my UI-code is structured in the following way:

```
class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    // SomePanel panel is added here
}
class SomePanel extends JPanel {
    // buttons, checkboxes and so on are added here
}
```

Lets say I'm instantiating a MainWindow-object inside my main method:

```
MainWindow frame = new MainWindow("I am an App");
```

What is the best practice for listening to ActionEvents of buttons (which are declared inside SomePanel, which is declared inside MainWindow) from within my main-method?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: See [*How to Use Actions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Comment: Also see [The humble dialog](http://home.arcor.de/fbdiplom/lit_pdf/fea02_thehumbledialogbox.pdf)

Comment: Thanks trashgod. EDIT: so you're suggesting writing custom ActionEvents?

Comment: Thank you Robin, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `PropertyChangeEvent`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513), to communicate results from one container to another. Other ways to implement the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Addendum: *You're suggesting writing custom `ActionEvents`?*

[`EventListenerList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) is another way to implement the observer pattern. Such a list is common to every `JComponent`, and it is appropriate when more than one event *type* must be managed. [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is another popular example that uses diverse events to update chart subcomponents when the data model is changed.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to have a closer look at this.