# how to repaint multiple JFrames

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, multiple-instances

I have a program that uses 2-3 JFrame objects at the same time and adds components during runtime. I need one JFrame to send a message to the others and get them to repaint themselves. I'm fairly knew to java so please forgive me if I'm being an idiot and missing something simple.

Comment: I think you should add the important parts of the code. With this question, I can only say: Iterate over your collection (or however you keep track of your frames that you want to repaint) of `JFrame`s and call `repaint()`

Comment: Have you tried the validate method? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Each component should be responsible for its own repaint(). So if you call a method from frame 1 to frame 2 (let's sat `notifyMessage(String)`, in the `notifyMessage(String)` you should call `repaint()`. This properly separates responsibility. Read also about [Multiple JFrame good/bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/928711)

Comment: Swing components repaint() themselves automatically. So you don't need to call repaint() or validate() or any method like that. You just need to update a component on the other dialog (don't use a JFrame) when the message is recieved and it will repaint itself.

Comment: I have the first frame repainting ok, but only after the user selects a refresh option from the menu. I had started working on a class to keep track of the frames but it looks like I might do better after reading up on layout managers and internal frames.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of [multiple frames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/230513), use a single frame and as many modeless dialogs as needed. You can use a [`PropertyChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) to ensure that updates in one container are propagated to another, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513).