# Changing the Text of A JLabel in Another Class (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

This has been confusing and irritating me for a while. I am working on a small program for a friend, and **basically,** it is a to-do list. Users can create a task with the `AddAssignment` class. There are a couple of fields the user must complete, but I am working on the first one, the task name. Once the task is saved, it is added to the list, which is in the `ViewAssignments` class. The JTextField for the task's name is known as `textField`.

I want the text of `lblAssignmentNa`, the JLabel in the `ViewAssignments` to be set to the text of `textField` on the press of `btnCreateAssignment`, a button in the `AddAssignment` class.

I'd appreciate only the code to change the JLabel's text to the same as `textField`'s text as an answer. Thanks. 
And I'm sorry if you don't understand any of this. Just let me know if you need more information.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/help this to know how to write questions, and please be shorter and show some code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to not call Class names as its behaviour AddAssigment is a bad name for a class.  Should be AddAssignmentPanel for example.

Second you should read this tutorial and then use it [Property Change Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html), (basically an implementation of `Observer Pattern`).

- `Observer` in your case is the class having `lblAssignmentNa`
  property (use `PropertyChangeListener`)
- `Observable` in your case is the class having `textfield` 
  property (Use `PropertyChangeSupport`)

So you have to do something like this.

1. Register the observer class into the observable class
2. When event happens, in your case, `btnCreateAssignment` pressed you should notify your observers.

So in `ViewAssigments` should be defined like this.

```
public class ViewAssigments extends Something implements PropertyChangeListener
```

In `AddAssigment` register `ViewAssigment` as an observer
In `btnCreateAssigment` event you have to call `propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(..)` and it's send to the observers to notify that state changes.

Additionally if your classes extends `JComponent` you have a PropertyChangeSupport instance ready for register `Listeners` and to `firePropertyChange(..)`

Comment: +1 for loose coupling; an example is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513).

Comment: Forgive, I've been rereading this answer for a while and it reads backward to me. I don't disagree with the basic intent though. AddAssignment has a button, btnCreateAssignment, which when triggered, wants to set the value of a label on ViewAssignment...this means that AddAssignment doesn't care about any property changes of ViewAssignment. The use of a PropertyChangeListener in this instance seems wrong to me, as the button isn't triggering change in any of the properties in the AddAssignment class.

Comment: It would have being simpler to just say "add a action listener from the ViewAssigment to the AddAssignment classes", but why should the ViewAssigment class even care about the AddAssignment class at all? Wouldn't it be better for the ViewAssignment to expose management functionality, perhaps via an interface, thus removing any ambiguity over how the values are changed

Comment: i think that ViewAssignment(observer) wants to observes a property of AddAssigment(observable) when an event happen. If you want to use it combine with a Mediator is a good solution :). @MadProgrammer

Comment: It is question of design and personal choice I guess. Personally I don't see the button click changing a property of the AddAssignment class

Answer (score 1):

Before answering you I'd like you to check this list :

[Writing perfect questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx)

You could just say : *How to set a lable's text to textField's text when button pressed*  instead of this paragrap. However this will help you :

```
jLabel.setText(textField.getText());
```

Comment: I realize my question was rather long. Secondly, I the JLabel I want the text to be changed of is in another class...

Answer (score 1):

Create some kind of setter method that can pass the request to the `ViewAssignments`, like `setAssignmentName` and when the user clicks the `btnCreateAssignment`, simply call the method, passing the `String` value from the `textField`.