# JOptionPane keeps on overlapping values on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, joptionpane

I'm new to JFrame, and I wanted to know why my JOptionPane won't stop popping up. When I type into the JOptionPane continuously, the values keep overlapping on the JFrame overtop of the previous ones, and it's keeping my program in a loop, preventing the printing process from opening up. I think it's because the program requests input values in a public void class rather than a public static void main class, but I don't know how to put these values on a JFrame otherwise because of the graphics component.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

import javax.swing.*;
public class Assignment3 extends JFrame
{
Assignment3()
{
    setTitle("Amber's Skateboarders");
    setSize(1200,720);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{   
    Font bigName = new Font("Ariel Bold", Font.BOLD, 20);
    Font company = new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 12);
    Font myList = new Font("Comic Sans", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    g.setFont(bigName);
    g.drawString("Skateboarders", 15, 100);
    String companyName;
    String companyAddress;
    int itemIndex = 0;
    int pricesIndex = 0;
    int quantityIndex = 0;
    String[] merchandise = new String[1000];
    double[] prices = new double[1000];
    int[] quantity = new int[1000];
    int addMore;
    String[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
    double subtotal = 0;
    double[] result = new double[1000];
    String[] list = new String[1000];

    companyName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your company name?");
    g.setFont(company);
    g.drawString(companyName, 15, 115);
    companyAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your company's address?");
    g.setFont(company);
    g.drawString(companyAddress, 15, 130);

    do
    {
        merchandise[itemIndex] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the name of the item you want?");
        prices[pricesIndex] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How much does this cost?"));
        quantity[quantityIndex] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How much of this item do you need?"));
        itemIndex++;
        pricesIndex++;
        quantityIndex++;
        addMore = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Do you want to add more to your shopping cart?", "Before you go!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,null, options, options[0]);
    }
    while(addMore == 0);
    int k;
    g.setFont(myList);
    if (addMore == 1)
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i <= pricesIndex-1; i++)
        {
            result[i] = prices[i]*quantity[i];
        }
        for (double j : result)
        {
            subtotal += j;
        }       
        for (k = 0; k<pricesIndex; k++)
        {
            list[k] = String.valueOf(quantity[k])+"\u00D7"+merchandise[k];
            g.drawString(list[k], 15, k*15+145);
            g.drawString("$" +String.valueOf(result[k]), 120, k*15+145);
            //all += String.valueOf(quantity[k])+"\u00D7"+merchandise[k]+"\t\t\t"+String.valueOf(result[k])+"\n";
        }
        k=pricesIndex;
        double taxes = subtotal*0.2;
        g.setFont(company);
        g.drawString("Subtotal: ", 15, k*15+145);
        g.drawString("$"+String.valueOf(subtotal), 120, k*15+145);
        k++;
        g.drawString("Tax: ", 15, k*15+145);
        g.drawString("$"+String.valueOf(taxes), 120, k*15+145);
        k++;
        g.drawString("Total: $", 15, k*15+145);
        g.drawString("$"+String.valueOf(taxes+subtotal), 120, k*15+145);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Assignment3 main = new Assignment3();
    main.paint(null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem in next:

1) You invoke your JOptionPane inside `paint()` method, it is'n proper way.

2) Why you draw your items with `Graphics`, I think you can use `JLabel`'s or `JTextField`'s as recommended by @trashgod. I recommend you to use `JTable`, i think it is suitable for your case. read [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for that.

3) You can add new items with help of button action([tutorial for button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)) instead of `while` looping.

4) If you want actually to draw your data on component. Extend `JPanel` class, add instance of it to your `JFrame` and paint in `paintComponents(Graphics g)` method.

Comment: Thank you! I looked into JLabel, and made all of my other variables into globals and used the function getContentPane().add(new JLabel(input)); to find everything in the paint method.

Unfortunately, I used graphics because I wanted to draw a couple small things in there, and I also get very excited about learning small things and jump into something before actually knowing how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks), "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`." It's also highly unusual to evoke a dialog in a callback that is not under you control. Since you're mostly calling `drawString()` you may find it easier to simply update components such as `JLabel` and `JTextField` via `setText()`. If you want to update the drawing area automatically, use a *modeless* dialog, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513).