# Passing from Jdialog to Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I've created a JDialog, and passed my JFrame in with it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < digiProdRadioBtns.length; i++) {
        if (digiProdCheck[i].isSelected()) {

            ProdDialog a = new ProdDialog(digiPopup[i], frame, digiProductList.getProduct(counter), digiProductList);
        }
```

I've then tried to access the methods of the JFrame from within the JDialog, but cannot.

```
public class ProdDialog extends JDialog {

cdDialog = new JDialog(jFrame, true);



 this.jframe = jFrame;
 jframe.newEmployee();
```

I've read that what I'm trying to do is possible, any reason as to why it's not working for me?

Comment: Please post a complete and compiled code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JFrame` and `JDialog` are [top-level containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) typically used as view components. In general, they don't communicate except to position a dialog relative to its parent frame. Instead, arrange for your views to communicate using a `PropertyChangeEvent`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513). Having a separate model that contains a notional `List<Product>` will let you employ the pattern discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing a lot of context here, what is it that is not working for you?

I assume you are seeing an error on the `jframe.newEmployee();` command saying that the method is undefined, if so then that is reasonable because the JFrame class does not have that method, if your class is class `ProdJFrame` and it extends JFrame and has that method, then you need to do `((ProdJFrame)jframe).newEmployee();`

Comment: Yes I should have explained more, so the set up is actually a JFrame called HomeScreen, I have implemented a card layout on this JFrame, so the Jpanel with the methods I want to access is called DigiProdPanel, this panel creates the JDialog, so maybe it's the panel "DigiProdPanel" I need to pass into the JDialog?