# extending JPanel and observable

Tags: java, swing, observable, observers

I am new to Java and I had a question.

I have a class that extends a `JPanel`. It Contains a `JButton`. If I press this button, I want another class to notice this. By doing so, I had read that I must use `Observer/Observable`.

Only problem is, I can extend it only once.. Any suggestions?

the two classes:

```
public class ControlsPanel extends JPanel{

    private JButton start;
    private JButton stop;
    private int animationSpeed = 5;
    private boolean startIsPressed;
    private CashRegistersPanel cr_panel;

    public ControlsPanel(final ParametersPanel panel) {

        start       = new JButton("Start");
        stop        = new JButton("Stop");

        start.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        stop.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));

        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(new Color(199,202,255));

        this.add(start);
        this.add(stop);

        start.setBounds(10, 10, 280, 30);
        stop.setBounds(10, 50, 280, 30);

        stop.setEnabled(false);

        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            if (start.getText().equals("Start")) {
                start.setText("Pause");
                stop.setEnabled(true);
                startIsPressed = true;
            }

            }
        });

        //For the STOP BUTTON
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (stop.isEnabled()) {
                    stop.setEnabled(false);
                    start.setText("Start");
                    startIsPressed = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean StartisPressed() {
        return startIsPressed;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CashRegistersPanel extends JPanel{

    private Image img;
    private int amount;
    private ParametersPanel parametersPanel;
    private ControlsPanel controlsPanel;
    private boolean startIsPressed;
    private CashRegister register;


    private ArrayList<CashRegister> myRegister = new ArrayList<CashRegister>();

    public CashRegistersPanel(ParametersPanel parametersPanel, ControlsPanel controlPanel) {

        startIsPressed = controlsPanel.StartisPressed();
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (startIsPressed) {
        Need to do the painting here
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you extending `JPanel`? Subclassing Swing classes should _only_ be done to add behavior, _not_ to control layout.

Comment: I have a JFrame class and two JPanel classes. In the first JPanel class I have a button. If this button is pressed, I want the second JPanel to draw a circle.

Comment: Use a `PropertyChangeEvent`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ActionListener in your class suppose MyPanel which is extending JPanel. Then you can pass the object of MyPanel in the ActionListener of the button.

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       // Your Drawing Code
    }
    //your other jpanel code
}
```

Create object of your customized JPanel

```
 MyPanel myPanel1;
```

Now you can pass the myPanel1 object as the ActionListener of the button.

```
button.addActionListener(myPanel1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have an ActionListener and if I press the button, a boolean isPressed becomes true. I want my second class to notice this change and draw a circle with graphics.

Comment: See my updated answer. Tell me if you have any issue.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me.. Hold on, let my paste a bit of my code and class. I am really stuck here and hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `ActionListener` to the `Jbutton` you want to monitor.

Comment: This won't work because yes I can add an ActionListener to the JButton (and I have), but the JPanel in the second class can't see if the button is pressed or not.

Comment: You can call a method on whatever class you want to notify that the Jbutton have been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't extend JPanel, there is not a single reason you should. Now, if you want the other class to notice you should use a controller as a sort version of the MVC pattern.

Comment: I have uploaded a bit of my code. Thanks, I will look up how to work with controller